# Свайп в jquery, библиотека jquery.mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

В общем дело такое, мне надо отследить свайп, я решил использовать jquery.mobile. Вот пример кода:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"> </script>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```

Вот код

```
viewport.swipe({
swipeLeft:function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {
   alert('swipe left');
}, 
swipeRight:function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {
   alert('swipe right');
}
});
```

В viewportсодержится

```
$('.indexReviewsVie_fu');
```

И сама ошибка

```
jquery.min.js:3 Uncaught TypeError: ((n.event.special[g.origType] || {}).handle || g.handler).apply is not a function
at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
at HTMLDivElement.r.handle (jquery.min.js:3)
at Object.trigger (jquery.min.js:3)
at e (jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js:3847)
at Object.handleSwipe (jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js:4022)
at HTMLDocument.e.move (jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js:4069)
at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
at HTMLDocument.r.handle (jquery.min.js:3)
```

И по итогу выдаёт ошибку, можете подсказать из-за чего ошибка?

Comment: А вашу ошибку, вы хотите, чтобы угадали? :) Добавьте в вопрос текст ошибки

Comment: Добавил, но мне кажется она мало чем поможет)

Comment: ээм может функцию нужно обернуть в $(), но это не точно))

Comment: Зачем оборачивать всю функцию в $(), если я правильно помню, то этот знак используется, для взаимодействия с DOM-элементом, а это уже есть в переменной. Можете написать как видите этот момент, может я просто неправильно понял

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка заключалась в том, что я сделал через переменную, в переменной была уже не строка а сам объект.